# install grub on pendrive containing linux installation, making it system independent

Tags: windows-7, linux, usb, bootloader

i have a win7 system and i want to install debian 6 on usb flash drive. the problem is grub loader. i want to install the grub loader on usb itself, so i can just plug in the pendrive in any computer and boot to deb6. so in effect making the flash drive an independent system. i tried it earlier, but ended up with grub loader needing me to insert the pendrive every time to give me boot options to even boot the win7 system, even though it was on primary hdd. so is there a way to turn the pendrive into full linux system with own boot loader, which can automatically detect os in the system i plug it in and be able to boot any of them. totally, self sufficient and system independent; making the pen drive so that it only needs a host system to run the os it carries. thank you, waiting for replies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `unetbootin`, it's a small multiplatform app that makes bootable usb and has support for lots of linux distros.

Comment: Or you can use syslinux, to setup booting manually.

Comment: Unetbootin is nice for live, non-persistent installations, maybe for semi-persistent, but not for full permanent installations.